# How do I allow the user to keep enter usernames?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, console-application

I want to allow the user to enter a username. The user name should then be stored in a file (create the file if it doesn't exist). However, the user should get an error if the username already exists in the file.

Once done the user should be able to enter a new username.

My problem is that I do not know how to keep asking for user names?

```
string fileName = ("Usernames.txt");
if (File.Exists(fileName))
    Console.WriteLine("Username file already exists!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Username file was created!");
    FileStream un = new FileStream("Usernames.txt",
        FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    StreamWriter kasutajanimed = new StreamWriter(un);
    Usernames.Close();

Console.WriteLine("Username: ");
string uCreation = Console.ReadLine();
bool exists = false;
foreach (string lines in File.ReadAllLines("Usernames.txt"))
{
    if (lines == uCreation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Username already exists!");
        exists = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!exists)
{
    File.AppendAllText(@"Usernames.txt", uCreation + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to our community. You need to adjust your question so that you ask about a specific problem. Tell us what doesn't work or which part of the code that you need help with.

Comment: Yes but now I cannot figure out a way to continue on with the code to ask for X things. Otherwise thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need another loop to let them enter another username.

```
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Username: ");
    string uCreation = Console.ReadLine();
    bool exists = false;

    foreach (string lines in File.ReadAllLines("Usernames.txt"))
    {
        if (lines == uCreation)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Username already exists!");
            exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!exists)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(@"Usernames.txt", uCreation + Environment.NewLine);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: When it asks for a username, And you enter one, It takes it and asks for a new one, Rather to continue with the code. And when you enter the same username twice, It says the username already exists and THEN it continues on with the rest of the code.
EDIT!
You seemed to fix it and that seemed to work for me! Thanks! :)

Comment: @CrimzonWeb Since the answer helped you, you should mark it as accepted. Consider upvoting the answer as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching the file in that fashion every time, it will be O(n) for each entry. I think the better way to do it is to keep a set that contains all usernames in the file. So add all username in the file to a HashSet when opening the file. Then you can simply call `hashSet.Contains(username)` to check if username exists in O(1) time.

For keep asking user, you can use a while true loop. like so

```
while (true) // Loop indefinitely
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Username: "); // Prompt
        string line = Console.ReadLine(); // Get string from user
        if (hashSet.Contains(line)) {
             Console.WriteLine("Username Already in Use");
             continue;
        }
        if (line == "exit") // have a way to exit, you can do whatever you want
        {
        break;
        }
        // Here add to both file and your HashSet...
    }
```